# Как посчитать кол-во результатов поиска в xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse.com

Есть 2 текст филда (make, year) и есть класс cars_new в  parse cloud. Хочу посчитать кол-во результатов под конкретные параметры введенные в текст филды, исходя из туториала код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"cars_new"];
[query whereKey:@"make" equalTo:@"Audi"];    
[query whereKey:@"year" equalTo:@"1992"];

[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error){
    if(!error){
        NSLog(@"Count: %i", number);
    }
```

Comment: в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Ну как сделать чтоб кол-во результатов поиска зависело от введенных данных? Сейчас понятное дело он считает только Ауди 1992 года даже если я ищу условные Тойоты Камри 2005

Answer (score 1):

Так создайте NSMutableDicrionary, положите в него данные из ваших  TextField, а потом уже юзайте вместо  @"Audi" значение из Dictionary.